# How to you use operator Int() of QFlags?

Tags: qt

Documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qflags.html#operator-Int

The question. I want to know what flags are set withouth testing one by one so I want the int number. Can anyone provide an example of how to use that operator in one of the many qt methods that rerturn a QFlags?

Comment: It means it does implicit conversion to an int in places which take an int.

Comment: The question is not specific to Qt. You're looking at the implicit conversion operator, a C++ feature. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16615725/1329652) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By referring to `QFlags.h` source code (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/android-emulator-build/qt/+/master/common/include/QtCore/qflags.h)

This is the definition in QFlags for "Int" operator.

```
Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline operator Int() const Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return i; }
```

And the "i" in return statement is declared as

```
Int i;
```

And the "Int" is declared as

```
typedef int Int
```

Notice the below two constructors of `QFlags`. The first constructor takes `Enum` as parameter and the second constructor takes `QFlag` as parameter.

```
Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline QFlags(Enum f) Q_DECL_NOTHROW : i(Int(f)) {}
Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline QFlags(QFlag f) Q_DECL_NOTHROW : i(f) {}
```

After noticing the above constructors, if `Enum` is passed to the constructor, the Enum can be a `signed` one or `unsigned` one. `QFlags` internally type casts it to `int` using `Int`.

Consider below example now.

```
//Qt::CursorShape is an Enum
Qt::CursorShape shape = Qt::ArrowCursor;

//Create QFlags object by passing "ENUM" as parameter
QFlags<Qt::CursorShape> qF(shape);

//Create QFlags object by just passing FLAG as a parameter
QFlags<Qt::CursorShape> q(Qt::ArrowCursor);
```

Now the situation where "Int" operator is called: In the below piece of code the first statement invokes `Int` operator and not in the second statement.

```
//Now try getting the values.
int test = qF; //In this case the "Int" operator is called.
int test1 = q;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This helped a lot.

Comment: Nice. Such comments are very motivating. Thanks.